# How do I get view to refresh when using workflow to edit a list value

Tags: list, workflow, list-view

I am using a simple workflow that's triggered on the creation of a list item to edit the value of a list item. The text description of the workflow is as follows:

```
Stage: Stage 1

Set MyField to Current Item:ID
then Email Joe Bloggs

Transition to stage

Go to End of Workflow
```

The edit happens, but it's not shown in the list view, even if I hit the browser's refresh button.

The edit only appears when I edit the list item via the UI.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it doesn't require an edit-via-UI to see the change, it just requires time. Refreshing several times over 10 seconds or so fixes it.

Strangely the email fires much quicker...